# wrapping y axis label in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, word-wrap

I would like to wrap my y label text (`Percentage of last observed tag detections`), so that it will be 2 lines of text instead of just 1 long line. I came across things like label_wrap, but did not manage to fix it.

```
ggplot(Mort_batchDO, aes(Date, n_bream))+
  geom_line(size = 0.8, col = "red")+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months", date_labels = "%m-%Y")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(n_bream) paste0(round(n_bream/10*100, digits= 0), "%"), breaks = seq(0, 10, by = 1))+
  ggtitle("Den Oever") + ylab("Percentage of last observed tag detections")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"))
```

dput:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18367, 18374, 18375, 18390, 
18418, 18787, 18791, 18844, 18858, 18858), class = "Date"), Transmitter = c("A69-1602-59771", 
"A69-1602-59778", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59774", 
"A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59776", 
"A69-1602-59769"), Batch.location = c("Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever"), Location.Receiver = c("Medemblik Ijsselmeer, gemaal", 
"Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Medemblik Ijsselmeer, inlaat", "Den Oever Ijsselmeer", 
"Makkum Ijsselmeer", "Medemblik Ijsselmeer, inlaat", "Medemblik Ijsselmeer, gemaal", 
"Medemblik Ijsselmeer, gemaal", "Den Oever Ijsselmeer", "Den Oever Ijsselmeer"
), Length = c(65, 66.2, 63.1, 62.5, 68.1, 65.7, 67.9, 65.7, 62.3, 
63.1), Weight = c(4112, 4029, 3535, 3404, 4868, 4105, 4553, 3998, 
2944, 3515), n_bream = 10:1), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000201ec2c1ef0>)
```

Comment: You can create a break by placing `\n` inside your label text

Comment: e.g., `ylab("Percentage of\nlast observed tag detections")`

Comment: Thank you so much! I would expect  a function or command, didn't know it was this easy :).